# Sending SMS in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sms

I am trying to send sms text in my mvc3 application to an sms gateway a but I get error in my application that

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'UrWeb.SMS.send(string)'"

**Reference Controller**

```
SMS.send(ViewBag.Message);
```

**SMS.cs**

```
private const string _user = "XXX";
    private const string _pass = "XXX";
    private const string _url = "http://sms.com/api/http.php";
    private const string Phone="000000000";
    public SMS(string _user, string _pass, string _url)
    {
        user = _user;
        pass = _pass;
        url = _url;
    }
        public string send(string Phone, string Message)
    {

        string strData = SMSGData(Phone, Phone, Message);
        return SendSms(url, strData);
    }
      .........
```

Any help in this direction will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your method [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
 public static string send(string Phone, string Message)
    { 
   ....
```

Comment: thanks ssilas777 When I change as you suggested the two lines of code that follows also gives similar error as the previous

Comment: You might have to make all methods static.